# Columns to row converting

Tags: sql, oracle, informatica

Table_A:

```
AA
BB
CC
DD
```

Output:

```
AA,BB,CC,DD
```

Any one help this

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 0):

`LISTAGG` seems to be one choice:

Sample data:

```
SQL> with table_a(col) as
  2  (select 'AA' from dual union all
  3   select 'BB' from dual union all
  4   select 'CC' from dual union all
  5   select 'DD' from dual
  6  )
```

Query:

```
  7  select listagg(col, ',') within group (order by col) result
  8  from table_a;

RESULT
------------------------------
AA,BB,CC,DD

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

informatica only solution -

1. SRT : sort the data by col1.
2. EXP : create 3 ports. make sure their length be >3000 char

```
in_col1 = col1
v_col1 = col1|v_col1
p_col1= col1
o_col1= v_col1
```

3. AGG: create 2 ports

```
in_col1 <-- link o_col1 from previous step2
o_col1 = MAX(in_col1) -- link this to final target
```

Normally, there should be a key column by which you want to aggregate the strings. if you have any, you need to change step2 in v_col1.